# Подскажите в чем проблема, что-то не могу понять?

Tags: laravel, npm

выдает ошибку

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/admin/Components/Form/Switch.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-15[0].rules[0].use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-15[0].rules[0].use[2]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-15[0].rules[0].use[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/admin/Components/Form/Switch.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options.url should be one of these:
   boolean | object { filter? }
   -> Allows to enables/disables `url()`/`image-set()` functions handling.
   -> Read more at https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#url
   Details:
    * options.url should be a boolean.
    * options.url should be an object:
      object { filter? }
    at validate (/Users/extrememod/projects/projects/Laravel/sberchange/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:105:11)
    at Object.getOptions (/Users/extrememod/projects/projects/Laravel/sberchange/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:529:19)
    at Object.loader (/Users/extrememod/projects/projects/Laravel/sberchange/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:31:27)
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.0",
        "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
        "sass": "^1.32.11",
        "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.7",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12",
        "vuex": "^3.6.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.2.8",
        "@websanova/vue-auth": "^4.1.4",
        "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
        "fibers": "^5.0.0",
        "v-tooltip": "^2.1.3",
        "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
        "vue-meta": "^2.4.0",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^4.3.1",
        "webpack": "^5.38.1"
    }
}
```

webpack.mix.js

```
mix
  .js('resources/js/admin.js', 'public/admin/js')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/web/js')
    .js('resources/js/web/exchange-processor.js', 'public/web/js')
    .js('resources/js/web/exchange-mask.js', 'public/web/js')
    .vue()
    .sass('resources/js/admin/Styles/admin.scss', 'public/admin/css')
    .sass('resources/js/admin/Styles/media.scss', 'public/admin/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/web/app.scss', 'public/web/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/web/media.scss', 'public/web/css');
```

Comment: конфиг sass-loader покажите (vue.config.js файл)

Comment: я использую laravel и в нем уже встроенный vue